# Как сделать динамический поддомен у себя на локалке для разработки?

Tags: веб-программирование, веб-сервер, dns, домен, поддомены

Как сделать динамический поддомен у себя на локалке для разработки?
узнал что в /etc/hosts нельзя сделать так 127.0.0.1   *.site.loc, на сервер смог сделать через dns менеджер хостинга, а на свом компе для разработки не могу найти решение

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/apache-ubuntu-14-04-lts-ru